# bootstrap dynamic navigation active class

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this nav bar:

```
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
```

and I'm using twitter bootstrap. I need to show one div per nav element and hide the rest of them, and also make the current menu item active at the right time, with all the others being inactive. Is there some code out there to do this?

Comment: bootstrap automatically does it for you, Have you included `bootstrap.min.js` file?

Comment: Yeh I have.. Surely I have to reference it or something

Comment: there is an updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#nav li a").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $("#nav li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any previously "active" li
    $("#home, #about, #contact").hide(); //Hide all "pages"
    $($(this).prop("href")).show(); //Show only the current target
    $(this).closest("li").addClass("active"); //Set click li as active
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about" data-toggle="tab">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact" data-toggle="tab">Contact</a></li>

</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">This is home</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="about">This is about</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="contact">This is contact</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="link_to_jquery"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="link_to_bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Here is a live preview : http://jsfiddle.net/v64NR/

Comment: I don't have separate pages for each, they're separate divs within the same page

Comment: If you have something like the above answer then it should work fine. @see : http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs